# HandsOff- Bot Framework C# with Dynamic365

Tags: c#, botframework

those days im trying to connect my azure bot(eco bot) with the omnichannel service from dynamics365.
I ate literally almost all documentations about it, but the microsoft docs isn't showing from a clear perspective.
If someone have a code example of how can I do it or an sample, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I think the entire future of the Azure connected ecosystem lies with Microsoft Graph, which is their unified REST services framework. You can look up how it works with Dynamics here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/dynamics-graph-reference?view=graph-rest-beta . To use Graph, you just install the nuget package and look at the docs.

Comment: Oh, thx, i'll take a look now and see with if i can apply it.

Comment: I got this working a year ago. I don't have exact steps but I used these docs. I had to do some massaging in D365, but I'm also no expert there: [Integrate an Azure bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-service/configure-bot-azure#integrate-azure-bots-with-omnichannel-for-customer-service), [Transition conversations from bot to human](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-design-pattern-handoff-human?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), [Handoff Library](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library)

Comment: I used this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/DynamicsOmnichannelBot) as a starting point. I believe I also referenced this video, [Microsoft Bot Framework in Omnichannel for Customer Service - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJNDEk2Lfi4). Between all of that I was able to get it working. Not super helpful, but maybe it will get you in the right direction. Wishing I still had the implementation but it was a sandbox environment that wasn't mine. I could switch both ways between bot and agent.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it'll help me. You have any methods to contact through? like email,telegram or something to ask questions. I'll study this material and will update if something works.